# I can't seem to use ^FTSE symbol from yahoo finance when importing the index into Python 3

Tags: python, pandas, import

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas_datareader import data as wb

tickers = ['^GSPC','^IXIC','^GDAXI','^FTSE']

ind_data = pd.DataFrame()

for t in tickers:
    ind_data[t] = wb.DataReader(t, data_source='yahoo', start='1997-1-1')['Adj Close']
```

Answer (score -1):

The following works:

```
ftse=pd.read_csv('https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/^ftse?period1=1058907192&period2=9999999999&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d',index_col=[0],parse_dates=True)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.